# Зачем нам 2 разных ссылки на временную шкалу?

Tags: обсуждение, инструменты-модератора

Есть две ссылки:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/742406/timeline - общедоступна
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/timeline/742406 - только для модераторов

Но модераторам по обеим ссылкам показывается одинаковая расширенная временная шкала. Я бы понял, если бы бы по модераторской ссылке показывалась модераторская шкала, а по обычной - обычная. Но вот то, как сделано сейчас, я не понимаю. В чём смысл?

Comment: на мета мете смотри, что-то вроде того, что делали модераторский инструмент и недоделали :)

Comment: `posts/742406/timeline` <-> `posts/timeline/742406` - индусы детект.

Comment: @Other, коммутативность детектед

Comment: @insolor, ещё хуже, значит не только для конечных пользователей вынос мозга, но и разрабам.